# Not able Install ruby 2.2.4 in mac os 10.15.6 catalina-openssl, ruby, zlib failing error

Tags: rvm, macos-catalina, ruby-install, ruby-build

I'm trying to install ruby 2.2.4 in mac os catalina 10.15.6 and it failing:

Error running 'env GEM_HOME=/Users/asmitakalena/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@global GEM_PATH= /Users/asmitakalena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin/ruby -d /Users/asmitakalena/.rvm/src/rubygems-3.0.8/setup.rb --no-document',
please read /Users/asmitakalena/.rvm/log/1600360212_ruby-2.2.4/rubygems.install.log

**An error log says:**

Exception `LoadError' at /Users/asmitakalena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems.rb:1222 - cannot load such file -- rubygems/defaults/operating_system Exception` LoadError' at /Users/asmitakalena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems.rb:1231 - cannot load such file -- rubygems/defaults/ruby
/Users/asmitakalena/.rvm/src/rubygems-3.0.8/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- openssl (LoadError) from /Users/asmitakalena/.rvm/src/rubygems-3.0.8/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in` require'
from /Users/asmitakalena/.rvm/src/rubygems-3.0.8/lib/rubygems/specification.rb:2481:in `to_ruby' from /Users/asmitakalena/.rvm/src/rubygems-3.0.8/lib/rubygems/commands/setup_command.rb:405:in` install_default_bundler_gem'
from /Users/asmitakalena/.rvm/src/rubygems-3.0.8/lib/rubygems/commands/setup_command.rb:167:in `execute' from /Users/asmitakalena/.rvm/src/rubygems-3.0.8/lib/rubygems/command.rb:321:in` invoke_with_build_args'
from /Users/asmitakalena/.rvm/src/rubygems-3.0.8/lib/rubygems/command_manager.rb:184:in `process_args' from /Users/asmitakalena/.rvm/src/rubygems-3.0.8/lib/rubygems/command_manager.rb:148:in` run'
from /Users/asmitakalena/.rvm/src/rubygems-3.0.8/lib/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:59:in `run' from setup.rb:41:in` '

**NOTE** I have already used these commands to make it work

- rvm install 2.2.4
- rvm reinstall 2.2.4 --with-openssl-dir=`brew --prefix openssl@1.1`
- rvm reinstall 2.2.4 --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr

It also failed bundle install with nokogiri error and I could not able to use install command anymore. It is trowing something like this

ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
cannot load such file -- zlib
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass

Any help will appreciate it. Thank you